# Pipes and graphics

Tags: graphics, fifo, programming, development

When developing a program (in C or Python, say), I often write debug messages to see whether my program behaves as intended. On Linux, such text messages can be handled in varied and flexible ways using tools like `grep`, `sed`, `wc`, etc.

However, once I want to display graphics instead of text messages, there is usually some pain involved. I'll have to link some graphics library to my program (after installing it, which can often be painful in itself) and figure out what boilerplate initialization is needed for the particular library.

**I am wondering whether something like the following exists.** Instead of linking a graphics library to our program, we would output our "graphical debug messages" to a pipe in a similar way to how we output our "text debug messages" to stdout. Then we redirect this pipe (stdout-graphics?) to some graphics viewer, which is run as a stand-alone program (similar to how we would run sed as a separate program, for example).

In my ideal world, I could do

```
gcc foo.c
./a.out 5>graphics_viewer
```

and see my "debug messages" (maybe some circles and points moving in 2D) generated by the program.

Some remarks:

- I don't know how much overhead we would incur from using pipes instead of direct calls to the graphics library. I also don't know how much of that overhead would be due to the coding of stdoutgraphics (i.e. can we use a text stream like "draw_rectangle(30,20,100,100); putpixel(3,7); flip();" or do we have to use a compressed format). Ideally we should be as universal as possible -- it would be good if using pipes was at most <10% slower than using the library natively.
- I don't know if there already are standard formats for "graphics instructions" in this context (say, covering all functionality of the SDL library). Of course there are many specialised languages for narrower domains, like PostScript and TikZ.
- Once we have stdoutgraphics, stdingraphics would also be handy.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this. Not by outputing primitive graphics commands, but by outputing status messages. Then writing a displayer that understands these messages, and display the right thing.

You can ether go for a fully custom displayer, or invent a more general language, that allows re-use.

## Also consider

Also consider using a **unit-test framework**. Unit-tests are the best way to test your code, especially when used with **test-driven-design**. (one of the first graphical output over stdout programs that I wrote was a test tool, and a test result visualiser.

## See also

- `dockviz` can output in `dot` format (directed and un-directed graphs(a graph is not a chart) ) (see https://graphviz.org/doc/info/command.html )